# How to create a type that takes an object and returns a modified version?

Tags: typescript

I need to type a function that takes an object and return a modified object like so:

```js
const data = {
  email: 'john@doe.com',
}

// This type is where I have trouble
type WrappedInput<T, K extends keyof T> = { [key: K]: { set: T[K] } }

function toInput<T = unknown>(data: T): WrappedInput<T> {
  return {
    email: {
      set: data.email
    }
  }
}
```

Every key should be wrapped under a `set` key.

Answer (score 4):

This is a relatively straightforward [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type WrappedInput<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { set: T[K] } }
```

Note the `in` operator in the type definition, indicating that this is a mapped type instead of a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). The above mapped type iterates over all the keys `K` in the union of keys `keyof T` and operates on them individually.

Then your implementation could possibly look like this:

```
function toInput<T>(data: T): WrappedInput<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k, { set: v }])
  ) as any;
}
```

(assuming your environment has `Object.fromEntries()` and `Object.entries()`).

And we can test it:

```
const inputData = toInput(data);
console.log(inputData.email.set.toUpperCase()) // JOHN@DOE.COM
```

Looks like what you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvGAoGMCmAtggJYA2AXDAOQBWIAFmAAJwj4B0oh1ANNgF9s2KAE8ADvhgB1AE4JxkuAEkw4gK5QAPABUAfGkwwA2gGkYJMDADW+USABmMHQF0qWCPihUdZlzAEA4Qd1MGAoEnAYKBBVDW19AApEZB8ASio5BSU4zV0DDFwYWS91WSsAeQAjWnxwjgdZEEIAUTAoWRJ8CETq2vr8ds7u5KQENI5icUTE42teGAA3FzS0AzmFjy8qRYCV1YQIGAQwUQBuQWFQSFhLeIARMcMY3KhR5DSL64gQMk4yEAAc0Sd00j2QHCIpDIHE8UA4MQAqop8LIAMKHfCJNKrAD0uJgACkKgAJAByzHuFRaHDRFQAskA)

Comment: Damn, I feel like an idiot. That looks exactly like what I need. Thanks man!